# What is the VIM equivalent for these two vscode shortcuts?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, vim, keyboard-shortcuts

the following are two common patterns I use with vscode:

[image]

[image]

Do you have any clue about what is the best way to get the equivalent result in VIM?

Thank you

Comment: I would try breaking the line before css and run: `:.s/\v\?\|/,\r/g`

Answer (score 3):

#1 would be a good candidate for a substitution:

```
:s/|/\r    /g
```

[image: #1]

where we substitute every `|` on the line with a carriage return followed by four spaces.

See `:help :substitute` and `:help sub-replace-special`.

#2 as well:

```
:'{,'}s/\s*$/,
```

[image: #2]

where we substitute any trailing whitespace character with a colon in the current paragraph.

See `:help :range`, `:help \s`, and `:help /$`.

Comment: For the second I would use: `:%norm A,`

Comment: @SergioAraujo, that would append a colon after the trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Vim Visual Multi](https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi)!

This should be able to do exactly the two things you want

1. `ctrl-n` roughly corresponds to `ctrl/cmd-d`.
2. `ctrl-shift-<Down>` adds a cursor under the current cursor. `9 ctrl-shift-<Down>` to add 9 of them.

That being said, this plugin seems to be more powerful than this. For example, it supports placing cursors by regex.